# How do I make a VLOOK up value show as a blank when the source cell is blank or if it shows as #N/A?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am attempting to create a formula to show the cells as a blank rather than return as `#N/A` or `0` or date of `00/01/1900`.

I can create a formula that returns a blank instead of `#N/A` and I can create a formula that returns a blank instead of a `0` or `00/01/1900`, however, I am looking to combine the two so I can drag it down the full column and if the source cell is blank it returns a blank or if it is an error it returns a blank.

Is it possible to combine two formulas below into the one cell?

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($C339,DBTRACKER,3,FALSE),"")

=IF(VLOOKUP($C339,DBTRACKER,3,FALSE)="","",VLOOKUP($C339,DBTRACKER,3,FALSE))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there with your second formula. I would use ISNA to check for the error as follows:

```
IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($C339,DBTRACKER,3,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP($C339,DBTRACKER,3,FALSE))
```

This will put a blank value in the cell if the lookup value is not found in the lookup table.

Answer (score 0):

*Your first formula needs little modification, and it should be like this:*

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP($C339,DBTRACKER,3,FALSE)="","",VLOOKUP($C339,DBTRACKER,3,FALSE)),"")
```

Comment: Rajesh this has worked in blanking the errors and the blank values from the lookup table, however, it has also taken away any values I would like to keep i.e. if there is a date in the look up table I would like to show this in the cell with the vlookup formula but if there is no data in the vlookup table or the cell doesn't exist I want the cell to remain blank without #N/A or 0 or 00/01/1900.

Comment: @Tony, this Lookup formula is exactly doing the same what you have written in comments, if finds the match value in C339 into DBTRACKER then shows it otherwise blank instead of error. if you share some sample data & the Match value in C339 I'll upload Screen Shot after been solved.

Comment: Rajesh the issue was the second dollar sign. The only constant is the C column the row needs to change each time. removing the second dollar sign has worked perfectly.

Comment: Just for your information the formula now reads: =IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP($C339,DBTRACKER,3,FALSE)="","",VLOOKUP($C339,DBTRACKER,3,FALSE)),"")       Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Tony, I've used $C$339 coz I thought that C has only one value to match otherwise I would have write $C339, anyways thanks, now I've edited the formula.